# How to receive messages without pressing enter in socket programming

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, python-3.7

I'm new to socket programming in Python and I'm trying to write a chatroom application, but I have a problem which is it each client should press enter in order to receive messages from other clients.

```
#my client side code
import socket 
import sys

client_sock = socket.socket() 
port = int(sys.argv[1])
client_sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', port))
print("Connected to server. start sending messages") 
while True:
    sending_message = input('> ')
    if sending_message:
        client_sock.send(sending_message.encode())
    receiving_message = client_sock.recv(1024)
    if  receiving_message:
        print(receiving_message.decode())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input` pauses your program. Thus, either you can't use `input` blindly, or you have to use threads. Using threads is easier than the alternative (using `select` to figure out what to do next). Have one thread for input and sending, one thread for receiving and printing.

Here's a trivial rewrite of your code:

```
import threading
import socket 
import sys

client_sock = socket.socket() 
port = int(sys.argv[1])
client_sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', port))
print("Connected to server. start sending messages")

def sender():
    while True:
        sending_message = input('> ')
        if sending_message:
            client_sock.send(sending_message.encode())

def receiver():
    while True:
        receiving_message = client_sock.recv(1024)
        if  receiving_message:
            print(receiving_message.decode()) 

sender_thread = threading.Thread(target=sender)
receiver_thread = threading.Thread(target=receiver)

sender_thread.start()
receiver_thread.start()

sender_thread.join()
receiver_thread.join()
```

Comment: Thank you very much but when i run it , encounter with this error: 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'join'

Comment: Corrected it, it should work now. You would still want to properly handle EOF instead of the infinite loop, as this is the most basic example.

Comment: what if i told you the problem hasn't solved yet as i see 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'start' error unfortunately!

Comment: Did you notice the change in the `sender_thread = threading.Thread(target=sender)` line (and the next one)?

Comment: Oops you are right. forgive me because of my carelessness. Anyway Thank you so much again.

Comment: No worries. Cheers.